# How would I create a table in Oracle 11g R2 from a SELECT AS and partition the table by range-list?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I am trying to create a new table called Titles2 from an existing table called Titles. I have to use a SELECT AS statement to create the columns in Titles2 from Titles. I also have to partition Titles2 by RANGE and then by LIST.

The code used to create Titles:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Titles
  2    (
  3    Title_id         char(3)     ,
  4    Title            varchar2(40),
  5    Genre            varchar2(10),
  6    Pages            number      ,
  7    Price            number(5,2) ,
  8    Sales            number      ,
  9    Pub_id           char(3)     ,
 10    Pubdate          date        ,
 11    Advance          number(9,2) ,
 12    Royalty_rate     number(5,2) ,
 13    CONSTRAINT Titles_pk PRIMARY KEY (title_id),
 14    CONSTRAINT Titles_Publishers_fk FOREIGN KEY (Pub_id)
 15                             REFERENCES Publishers (pub_id)
 16    )
 17    PARTITION BY RANGE (Pubdate) (
 18    PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-1995', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) TABLESPACE TSLab8ben1,
 19    PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) TABLESPACE TSLab8ben2,
 20    PARTITION P3 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) TABLESPACE TSLab8ben3
 21    );

Table created.
```

The following code is what I have so far for creating a Titles2 table from Titles:

```
CREATE TABLE Titles2 AS
SELECT Title_id AS TID, Title, Genre, Sales, (Sales * Price) AS Revenue, Pub_id AS P#
FROM Titles
PARTITION BY RANGE (Revenue)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (Genre)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
SUBPARTITION G1 VALUES ('history', 'biography'),
SUBPARTITION G2 VALUES ('computer','children'),
SUBPARTITION G3 VALUES (DEFAULT)) (
PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (100000),
PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (500000),
PARTITION P3 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
PARTITION P4 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

However, the code for creating Titles2 doesn't execute. Would anybody be able to help me get the Titles2 code to execute? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `Titles2` to be created with a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`?  Why can't you just use a `CREATE TABLE` command to create `Titles2` and then do an `INSERT INTO titles2 SELECT <<columns>> FROM titles` to populate the data?

Answer (score 13):

Create table `Titles2` using just `create table` statement(not CTAS) with appropriate partitions just like you did with `Titles`. And then use `insert` statement to populate `Titles2` with data from `Titles`

```
insert into Titles2 
  select <<columns>>
    from Titles
```

Or you can rewrite your last `create table` statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Titles2
  PARTITION BY RANGE (Revenue)(
    SUBPARTITION BY LIST (Genre)
    SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
    SUBPARTITION G1 VALUES ('history', 'biography'),
    SUBPARTITION G2 VALUES ('computer','children'),
    SUBPARTITION G3 VALUES (DEFAULT)) (
    PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (100000),
    PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (500000),
    PARTITION P3 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
    PARTITION P4 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))
   ) AS
SELECT Title_id AS TID
     , Title
     , Genre
     , Sales
     , (Sales * Price) AS Revenue
     , Pub_id AS P#
FROM Titles
```